# How do you get angry grandmas in cookie clicker?

Tags: cookie-clicker

I have no idea how to get angry grandmas. I have the Bingo/Research Facility upgrade but I don't know how to get the upgrades that are being researched.

Comment: https://cookieclicker.fandom.com/wiki/Grandmapocalypse

Answer (score 2):

Get atleast 7 grandmas and 7 grandma types.

Get the Bingo center/Research facility and buy the new upgrades from that. It will start the grandma apocalypse.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have 7 types of grandmas, then make sure you're waiting long enough, the bingo center takes time to research, approx. 30 minutes, but it can be reduced with the ascension upgrade "Persistent Memory".

Answer (score 0):

In order to start the grandmapocolypse, you must first purchase 7 of the upgrades that give you more grandma types, then you must buy the upgrade that unlocks the research, the Bingo center/Research facility upgrade (1 quadrillion cookies) which you already have as you mentioned, and then you must purchase 4 of those researched upgrades (each takes 1/2 hour to research) to get to the upgrade named One Mind (~15 quadrillion cookies), and once you purchase that, the grand matriarchs will get angry and buying further updrades will get the grandmas angrier and wrinklers will start spawning as a result until you make an Elder Pledge or Covenant.